# How to generate a 3D spherical symmetric object from a 2D circular graph?

Tags: image, graph, 3d, geometry

I have a very simple 2d graph.

6 lines separated by equal angle of 60 degrees radiate from the center of a 2d circle, intersecting with the circumference at 6 points.
Suppose I know the coordinates of these 6 points, my question is how to turn this graph into a 3d spherical symmetric graph? New lines will be radiating from the center of the sphere, intersecting with the sphere at new points, and how to convert the coordinates of the 6 old points to the coordinates of new vertices on the sphere?

The question seems to be trivial but didn't figure out how to do this. 
Need some help, thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics. The [Math StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: I don't think you tell us all you should. Appending a third coordinate with value 0 will turn your 2D points on a circle to 3D coplanar points on a sphere.

Comment: Cross reference: This question has now been [posted on the Math StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/682303/35416).

Answer (score 0):

You might have to elaborate what your symmetry requirements exactly are. But the image I have in my mind when I just read “symmetric” is one where the convex hull of the points on the sphere would be a [Platonic solid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid). And since none of these has a six-fold rotational symmetry, this would be impossible.

But perhaps I'm misreading the question in some other way. Perhaps you don't want to preserve the six-fold planar symmetry, but want six points in total on the sphere. A symmetric arrangement would be the corners of an octahedron, or equivalently the centers of the sides of a cube. Then the simplest coordinates would be:

```
(1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 0),
(0, 1, 0), (0, -1, 0),
(0, 0, 1), (0, 0, -1)
```

Comment: MvG, thanks for replying. Sorry for confusion. What I want is how to generate a spherical symmetry from a six-fold planar symmetry, a cross section of the spherical symmetric object should give me back the six-fold symmetric plane. So there should be more than 6 points on the sphere.